# Rails: uninitialized constant WelcomeController routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting dreaded routing error. Ubuntu 16.04 running on Win10. Rails 2.4.1. Using Sublime.

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get "welcome/home", to: "welcome#home"

end
```

**I do have a welcome_controller.rb (in app/controllers):**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

end
```

Have tried quite a few solutions here on SO but can't seem to get this to work. Note: I do restart rails after each change to see changes. 
**Additional logging I can do? Different code?**

```
Full Trace:
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:85:in `controller_class_for'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:78:in `controller_class'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `controller'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Routes:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern             Controller#Action
welcome_home GET  /welcome/home(.:format) welcome#home
```

Application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Mattsapp
class Application < Rails::Application

config.load_defaults 5.1

end
end
```

Development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.quiet = true

  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Comment: URL is: http://localhost:3000/welcome/home/

Comment: Post the stack trace of the Error because nothing you have posted here is technically incorrect excepting the fact that you do not have a `home` method defined in the `WelcomeController` but that will not raise the error you are referencing

Comment: @codeclimb since is your welcome controller and your home method, why not just use root 'welcome#home' on your routes.rb file

Comment: @engineersmnky  -  Started GET "/welcomes/home/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-21 13:10:47 -0600

**ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant WelcomesController):**

activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'

Comment: @codeclimb "/welcomes/home" and "/welcome/home" are not the same thing `WelcomesController`  should have nothing to do with this double check your typing to make sure you are visting "/welcome/home" and that the route looks like `get 'welcome/home', to: 'welcome#home'` with no **s**

Comment: @engineersmnky - I understand - the spelling is correct. I only changed the name to try something someone posted here as a solution. Dont be confused - I have meticulously gone over the spellings etc and it is correct. It is currently back to singular. Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you call the `UsersController` in the console? Just open the console (`$ rails c`) and then call the controller (`> WelcomeController`)

Comment: @Tobias   ---   irb(main):001:0> WelcomeController
NameError: uninitialized constant WelcomeController
        from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0>    ------    irb(main):002:0> UsersController
NameError: uninitialized constant UsersController
        from (irb):2
irb(main):003:0>

Comment: It looks like autoloading has problems... could you add the `application.rb` and the `development.rb` to the question?

Comment: @Tobias - added both thanks

Comment: Hmm looks ok to me. If you send me a link to the project repository I can take a deeper look. Maybe it's not the project but the installed Ruby.

Comment: @Tobias et all - thanks for replies. I am going to bail on the local Ubuntu subsystem running on Win10 because of all the issues everyone reports. I am moving to cloud9 so as to not waste more time. I'm new and learning and need to keep moving forward. How can I "close" this issue? Thx again.

Comment: Ok there is no way to "close" a question.. it's a Q&A platform. But if you want to help others you can answer your question then by yourself if you solved it and mark it as answer.

Comment: Btw Controller should ideally be named plural - by rails convention. E.g. WelcomesController.rb

Comment: @BKSpurgeon WelcomeController is totally fine. This convention applies more to RESTful resources. E.g. UsersController. But if you don't intend to use it for this it's ok. And also there is now plural for welcome so it just sounds strange.

Answer (score 1):

Add a def home function and leave it empty in your welcome controller. like this. if you want it to  do something, you can add you to it. But for now, leave it empty!

```
def home
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try making your path relative to root by adding   / before it

```
  get "/welcome/home",  to: "welcome#home"
```

and add home action to your controller...

```
 Class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
   def home
   end
 end
```

Comment: This did not help :(

Comment: @codeclimb make sure to add the home method to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Consensus is that configs are right here (rails) but likely a problem with the Win10/Ubuntu setup. I won't be investigating this further. If I come across something I will update the thread.